# C - Strcmp() not working

Tags: c, strcmp

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{

const int SIZE = 100;

char input[SIZE];

while(1)
{
    fgets (input, SIZE - 2, stdin);          // input
    printf("%d", strcmp(input, "exit"));    //returining 10 instead of 0

    if(strcmp(input, "exit") == 0)
    {
        printf("SHELL Terminated\n");
        exit(0);    
    }

return 0;
}
```

I am facing a problem. If I enter **exit** in `input` variable, the function `strcmp()` returns `10`, but it should return `0` and exit the program as **exit** is equal to **exit**.   But it does not.

I can't find the problem.

Comment: Have you tried printing your `input` variable first?

Comment: @cad space for null character...

Comment: Googling your exact title gives: 'About 60,500 results', with three SO Q&A about the 'newline' issue as the first three entries.

Comment: @Muzahir Hussain: Firstly, why would you reserve *two* bytes for *one* null character? Secondly, `fgets` already knows to reserve space for null character internally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgets` appends a newline (`\n`) character to the end of the string read into the buffer.

Delete it using

```
char* newline = strchr(input, '\n');
if (newline)
    *newline = '\0';
```

[As @WeatherVane mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291605/c-strcmp-not-working?noredirect=1#comment60209198_36291659), some calls of `fgets` might not set a newline in the buffer, so we need to check if `strchr` returns `NULL` (no newline found).

Comment: This method will break if the last line of a file does not have `newline`, or if the input buffer passed to `fgets` was shorter than the text line length.

Comment: Yes, but, alk and vlad have a better way.

Comment: @WeatherVane ...which I wholeheartedly agree with. :-)

Comment: Yes, `fgets` can append a newline character. But using `strchr` to search for it is an atrocity.

Comment: @AnT How is it an "atrocity"?

Comment: @cad: It generates more heat than light, speaking figuratively. Why are you *searching* for something, if you already know where it shall be (if it is present).

Comment: @AnT `fgets` doesn't provide information about the length of the string and the location of the newline, so why **not** search it?

Comment: @cad: OK, makes sense, I guess. Still, `strlen` is theoretically (and often practically) a more efficient way to find the end of the string, and then check for newline manually.

Answer (score 8):

You get `10` because there is a newline character in your input string. the `10` return value is the difference between the ascii value of that newline character and the terminating null character of the `"exit"` string literal you're comparing to.

Answer (score 6):

Function `fgets` also includes the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds for example to the pressed Enter key if there is enough space in the array.

You should remove it for example the following way

```
fgets( input, SIZE, stdin );
input[strcspn( input, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

or more safe

```
if ( fgets( input, SIZE, stdin ) != NULL ) input[strcspn( input, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

Take into account that this code

```
*strchr(input, '\n') = '\0';
```

in general is invalid because the new line character can be absent in the array and the function `strchr` will return `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

`fgets()` keeps the `'\n'`. You either remove it from `input` (see other answers) or add it to the literal

```
strcmp(input, "exit\n")
```